# Projection that preserves pairwise distance of $n$ data points

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $n$ points $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n \}\in \mathbb{R}^d$. How can I show that, if $d>n$, there exists a projection $P\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ to an $n$ dimensional subspace such that $\|Px_i-Px_j\|_2=\|x_i-x_j\|_2$? i.e., the projection preserves the pairwise distances.

Notice $P$ cannot be simply an orthogonal projection: $P^TP\neq I_{d\times d}$ since the rank is at most $n<d$. Can anyone helps me on this?

Comment: Hint: the set of vectors formed by differences of the $x_i$ span the projection subspace.

Comment: @Paul That set lies in $\mathbb{R}^d$ but the subspace is in $\mathbb{R}^n$? And I don't see how it relates to the $L_2$ norm equivalence?